# How to Stop a specific virtualhost in apache2

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost, virtual-host

let's say I want to stop only the *example2* VirtualHost. How do I do it?

`sudo service apache2 stop` will stop all the VirtualHosts. I want *example1* to keep running

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName www.example1.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example1

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName www.example2.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example2

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of would be to comment out the entire VirtualHost block for the one you want stopped, and reload Apache config.

For future reference, a better way to set up your configurations would be to have each VirtualHost block in a separate file in `sites-available/`, and symlink to them from `sites-enabled/`. In this way, to disable a site you would just remove the symlink and then reload apache config (no commenting required).